# Split the list in two parts Python

Tags: python, list

I want to split the values of the list in two parts using the initial mean value. I have a list of values and I have just find mean of the list which gives me the mean value of the list.

Now I want to split like <= mean value in one list and bigger values into other part.

I have below code:

```
import numpy as np
StoreList = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
mean_value = np.mean(StoreList)
print(mean_value)

size = len(StoreList)
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in enumerate(StoreList) if val <= 
mean_value]


res = [StoreList[i: j] for i, j in zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + ([size] if 
idx_list[-1] != size else []))]
print("list after value : " + str(res))
```

For the above I got output as follows:

```
Mean Value : 1.8571428571428572
list after value : [[1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
```

But I want below output:

```
list after value : [1,1,1], [2,3,2,3]
```

Comment: So you want to make a list and give it an integer and then output all the values equal to the integer in one list and in the other the rest of them??

Comment: `res = [[i for i in StoreList if i <= mean_value], [i for i in StoreList if i > mean_value]]`

Comment: @Filip: Yes you understand correctly.

Comment: @filbranden: Thanks a lot.

Comment: @filbranden: I am doing mistake in for and if loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if you can tolerate two iterations:

```
small_list = [i for i in StoreList if i <= mean_value]
big_list = [i for i in StoreList if i > mean_value]

together = [small_list, big_list]
```

building both lists iteratively:

```
small_list, big_list = [],[]

for i in StoreList:
    if i <= mean_value:
         small_list.append(i)
    else: 
         big_list.append(i)
```

Comment: the problem here is that you have to go through it twice

Comment: Don't use a `a if b else c` expression for the last part. You're not using the final value, so there's no reason for it. Just use a regular if/else. It's 4 lines, but who's counting? It's the most pythonic form. `if i <= mean_value:`, `small_list.append(i)`, `else:`, `big_list.append(i)`. You might want to consider using "smaller" and "larger" or "greater" or so for the names. But this is the best answer to this question.

Comment: Looping twice is not too bad, it's still linear on the length of the list. (In Big-O notation, this algorithm is still O(n), so it's still fine.)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using NumPy, you could just use NumPy's ability to index with predicates like:

```
import numpy as np

storeList = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1])
mean = np.mean(storeList)

low, high = storeList[storeList < mean], storeList[storeList >= mean]
```

This does go through the list twice, but should be quite fast (and probably much faster than anything using an explicit for loop).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single pass on a single line using reduce from functools:

```
from functools import reduce
res = reduce(lambda r,v:r[v>mean_value].append(v) or r,StoreList,([],[]))
```

output:

```
print(res) # ([1, 1, 1],[2, 3, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

filter is the first thing that came to mind:

```
>>> store_list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
>>> mean_value = np.mean(store_list)
>>> 
>>> lt_vals = filter(lambda x: x <= mean_value, store_list)
>>> gt_vals = filter(lambda x: x > mean_value, store_list)
>>> 
>>> # Either iterate over them as is, or convert.
>>> list(lt_vals)
[1, 1, 1]
>>> list(gt_vals)
[2, 3, 2, 3]
>>>
```